# python importing in cmd however not when launching a .py file

Tags: python, pandas, package, python-import

Seeking advice. Using Anaconda or the standard python prompt i can import packages fine. When making a .py file and double clicking it the script inside will not import any installed packages.

Pre installed such as tkinter, json work fine however manually installed ones such as pandas will not import.

im using the following to test.

```
try:
  import pandas
except:
    f = open("errorlog.txt", "a")
    f.write("could not import")
    f.close()
```

I may be missing something here but cant understand why it will work on one but not the other.

Comment: how many python installations do you have?

Comment: I think i may have two, as i installed anaconda but could not use the package library the way i needed to so installed the python 3.8 manually from the website.